# Is there a way to use EF.Functions.Like with ESCAPE sql keyword to prevent wildcard

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

So I am implementing a search function against a table with a varchar field containing text usually with simple strings, but some of them contain '[Text]', including the brackets.

For the filtering function i'm using Entity Framework and trying to use EF.Functions.Like like:

```
objects = objects.Where(t => EF.Functions.Like(t.name, "%" + param.Request.Name + "%"));
```

The problem is when the object.name contains those brackets because it triggers the SQL Charlist wildcard so the above returns 0 results; I can't find any information on how to use this in tandem with the SQL ESCAPE keyword like so:

```
...WHERE NAME LIKE '%PRETEXT_\[TEXT\]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

where the above statement returns any result containing PRETEXT_[TEXT]

Is there any way  to do use ESCAPE with these so I can escape the '[' + ']' characters, or another/better way of going about this sort of thing?

Comment: Escape opening `[` with `[[]` and you don't need to escape closing `]`, e.g. `'%Tariff [[]Account]%'` finds anything with "Tariff [Account]" in it.

Comment: i always forget.. but does `t.name.Contains(param.Request.Name)` not work?

Comment: As JamieD77 says, Contains will work in this scenario as well and does not involve string manipulation. I Have accepted an answer that pertains specifically to the EF.Functions.Like and provided an example below if anyone else stumbles here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation:

```
public static bool Like (this Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbFunctions _, string matchExpression, string pattern, string escapeCharacter);
```

You can add the escape character as an additional argument.

Like JamieD77 said Contains should work as well with no string manipulation.

Comment: `param.Request.Name = param.Request.Name.Replace("[", "\\[");`  
`param.Request.Name = param.Request.Name.Replace("]", "\\]");`  
  
`objects = objects.Where(t => EF.Functions.Like(t.name, "%" +  param.Request.Name + "%", "\\"));`  

Seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: Always nice to include a [link to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctionsextensions.like?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbfunctionsextensions-like(microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbfunctions-system-string-system-string-system-string)) when you cite the documentation :)